# JMeter - XMPP Authentication

Tags: xmpp, jmeter

I am building a test plan to test XMPP with JMeter. But I always meet an error when I send a authentication string to server even the authentication string is correct. Does anybody have the same problem or know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

```
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 ERROR - ru.yandex.jmeter.XMPPClientImpl: Error reading data java.lang.RuntimeException: Retries more than 1000, aborting read
at ru.yandex.jmeter.XMPPClientImpl.read(XMPPClientImpl.java:116)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:414)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2014/07/04 10:23:22 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading data
at ru.yandex.jmeter.XMPPClientImpl.read(XMPPClientImpl.java:152)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:414)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Retries more than 1000, aborting read
at ru.yandex.jmeter.XMPPClientImpl.read(XMPPClientImpl.java:116)
... 4 more

2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2014/07/04 10:23:22 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: Could you show your test plan, zoom on XMPPSampler and show your configuration

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8hlav0mdnmmhrw/xmpp.png
Youc can refer to the link to check my config.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem with the XMPPClientImpl plugin. I've added the BeanShell Listener to see if I can get any extra debugging info but no use, I just get useless info like you posted above. The server I'm trying to test is an Openfire chat server and its logs don't even show any connection attempts from the Jmeter front-end. My next step is to use Wireshark to see if I can grab any useful responses as the test plan runs, but I'm not hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried using XMPPClientImpl plugin but always got the same error ("Retries more than 1000, aborting read"), so I decided to leave it and write my own code.

I use a BeanShell Sampler in which I run the following code (using [smack](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) library) to connect to XMPP server.

```
String CLASS_PATH = "C:/JMeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/lib/ext/smack/";

addClassPath(CLASS_PATH + "smack-android-extensions-4.1.3.jar");
addClassPath(CLASS_PATH + "smack-tcp-4.1.3.jar");
addClassPath(CLASS_PATH + "smack-android-4.1.3.jar");

// explicitly import every class you need 
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException.XMPPErrorException;

String jabberId = "...";
String jabberPass = "...";

String SERVER_ADDRESS = "...";
int    PORT =  5222;  // or any other port

XMPPTCPConnection getConnection() {

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config  = 
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
           .setUsernameAndPassword(jabberId, jabberPass)
           .setHost(SERVER_ADDRESS)
           .setServiceName(SERVER_ADDRESS)
           .setPort(DEFAULT_PORT)
        // .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
           .setSendPresence(true)
        // .setDebuggerEnabled(YouMe.DEBUG)
           .build();

   XMPPTCPConnection con = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

   int REPLY_TIMEOUT = 50000;  // 50 seconds, but can be shorter
   con.setPacketReplyTimeout(REPLY_TIMEOUT);

   return con;
}
```

Don't forget to add the smack path (e.g. C:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\smack) to the library field (under "**Add directory or jar classpath**") in the Test Plan node of your test plan.

To connect -

```
con = getConnection();
con.connect();
```

To login -

```
con.login(jabberId, jabberPass);
```

You can also add connection listener -

```
ConnectionListener listener = new ConnectionListener() {  

    public void  connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
            // run main code incl. the login code
            runMain();
    }
    public void  authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnection, boolean resumed) {
    }
    public void connectionClosed() {
    }
    public void  connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
    }
    public void  reconnectingIn(int i) {
    }
    public void  reconnectionSuccessful() {
    }
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
    }
    }; 

con.addConnectionListener(listener);

// connect
con.connect();

runMain() {
    con.login(jabberId, jabberPass);

    // ...
}
```